# Add columns to pandas dataframe from two separate dataframes with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'll admit that this question is quite specific. I'm trying to write a function that reads two time columns (same label) in separate dataframes `df1['gps']` and `df2['gps']`. I want to look for elements in the first column which are close to those in the second column, not necessarily in same row. When the condition on time distance is met, I want to save the close elements in `df1['gps']` and `df1['gps']` in a new dataframe called `coinc` in separate columns `coinc['gps1']` and `coinc['gps2']` in the fastest and most efficient way. This is my code:

```
def find_coinc(df1, df2=None, tdelta=.25, shift=0):
    index_boolean = False
    if df2 is None:
        df2 = df1.copy()

    coincs = pd.DataFrame()
    for _, r1 in tqdm(df1.iterrows(), total=len(df1)):
        ctrig = df2.loc[abs(r1.gps+shift-df2.gps)<tdelta]
        print(r1.gps)
        coincs_single = pd.DataFrame()
        if len(ctrig)>0:
            coincs_single['gps1'] = r1.gps
            coincs_single['gps2'] = ctrig.gps                               
            coincs = pd.concat((coincs, coincs_single), axis = 0, ignore_index=index_boolean)                
            index_boolean=True
        else:
            pass
    return coincs
```

The script runs fine, but when investigating the output, I find that one column of `coinc` is all NaN and I don't understand why. Test case with generated data:

```
a = pd.DataFrame()    #define dataframes and fill them
b = pd.DataFrame()
a['gps'] = [0.12, 0.13, 0.6, 0.7]
b['gps'] = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83]

find_coinc(a, b, 0.16, 0)
```

The output yielded is:

```
    gps1 gps2
0   NaN 0.10
1   NaN 0.10
2   NaN 0.50
3   NaN 0.81
4   NaN 0.82
5   NaN 0.83
```

How can I write `coinc` so that both columns turn out fine?

Comment: Please add example data to your question

Comment: Thanks @JohannesSchöck, I added some mock data.

Comment: Could the serie 'ctrig' has more than 1 value?

Comment: @JLMelandri8 yes, as a matter of fact I posted an answer which apparently fixes exactly this. I don't know if there are better, more correct ways though to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is another solution. Instead of concat two dataframes just add new rows to 'coincs' DataFrame. I will show you below.

```py
def find_coinc(df1, df2=None, tdelta=.25, shift=0):
    if df2 is None:
        df2 = df1.copy()

    coincs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['gps1', 'gps2'])
    for _, r1 in tqdm(df1.iterrows(), total=len(df1)):
        ctrig = df2.loc[abs(r1.gps+shift-df2.gps) < tdelta]
        if len(ctrig)>0:
            for ctrig_value in ctrig['gps']:
                # Add n rows based on 'ctrig' length.
                coincs.loc[len(coincs)] = [r1.gps, ctrig_value]
        else:
            pass
    return coincs

# -------------------

a = pd.DataFrame()  # define dataframes and fill them
b = pd.DataFrame()
a['gps'] = [0.12, 0.13, 0.6, 0.7]
b['gps'] = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83]

coins = find_coinc(a, b, 0.16, 0)

print('\n\n')
print(coins.to_string())
```

**Result:**

```
   gps1  gps2
0  0.12  0.10
1  0.13  0.10
2  0.60  0.50
3  0.70  0.81
4  0.70  0.82
5  0.70  0.83
```

I hope I could help! :D

Comment: Thanks,  running this  script seems faster with larger dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that there are multiple elements in `df2['gps']` which satisfy the condition of being within a time window of `df1['gps']`. I think I found a solution, but looking for a better one if possible. Highlighting the modified line in the original function as ### FIX UPDATE comment:

```
def find_coinc(df1, df2=None, tdelta=.25, shift=0):
    index_boolean = False
    if df2 is None:
        df2 = df1.copy()

    coincs = pd.DataFrame()
    for _, r1 in tqdm(df1.iterrows(), total=len(df1)):
        ctrig = df2.loc[abs(r1.gps+shift-df2.gps)<tdelta]
        ctrig.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        coincs_single = pd.DataFrame()
        if len(ctrig)>0:
            coincs_single['gps1'] = [r1.gps]*len(ctrig)  ### FIX UPDATE
            coincs_single['gps2'] = ctrig.gps 
            print(ctrig.gps)
            coincs = pd.concat((coincs, coincs_single), axis = 0, ignore_index=index_boolean)
            index_boolean=True
        else:
            pass
    return coincs
```

The solution I chose, since I want to have all the instances of the condition being met, was to write the same element in `df1['gps']` into `coinc['gps1']` the needed amount of times.